# Reset chart count with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that copies 14 charts into a chart sheet and then a separate macro that sorts through the charts based on chart number and deletes them based on varying criteria. The problem is if I delete all the charts and re run the initial macro the chart on the chart sheet now start at 15 so the second macro does not work again. Is there a way to reset the chart count? or probably a different better way to do it?

```
Sub cut()
Dim x As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim q As Date
Dim w As Date
Dim e As Date
Dim r As Date
Dim t As Integer

Sheets("Details").Select
x = ActiveSheet.Cells(56, 2)
i = ActiveSheet.Cells(54, 2)
q = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 2)
w = ActiveSheet.Cells(40, 2)
e = ActiveSheet.Cells(38, 2)
r = ActiveSheet.Cells(36, 2)
t = ActiveSheet.Cells(57, 2)

    If x = 0 Then
    Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("Chart 10").delete
    End If
    
    If i = 0 Then
    Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("Chart 12").delete
    Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("Chart 13").delete
    Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("Chart 14").delete
    End If
    
    If q < w Then
    Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("Chart 4").delete
    End If
    
    If q < e Then
    Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("Chart 3").delete
    End If
    
    If q < r Then
    Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("Chart 2").delete
    End If
    
    If q = t Then
    Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("Chart 9").delete
    End If

    If q > t Then
    Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("Chart 10").delete
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Always helps to post the code you're working with...

Comment: Hopefully this helps to give some clarity

Comment: `for each c in ActiveSheet.chartobjects:c.name="Chart" & i:i=i+1:next c`

Comment: Similar to Nathan's comment - if you're relying on addressing specific charts by name, you need to name them when you create/recreate them.  Otherwise your code can't be robust.  Alternatively, if the charts are always in the same position you can get to each one via it's `TopLeftCell` property.   Using `Name` is a better approach though.